# Generate proxy classes for Java 1.4

Tags: java, web-services

I have:

- `WCF` web service created on `C#`.
- `Java 1.4` project that needs to use `WCF` service.

I can generate proxy classes with `wsimport.exe` from `jdk1.7` without problems, but classes are generate for higher Java versions. `JDK 1.4` does not contain `wsimport` utility. How to generate classes for `Java 1.4`?

Comment: NO one should be using a JVM that old anymore.

Comment: @duffymo: Some people don't have a choice of what JVM to use.

Comment: 5.0 public updates ended in 2009 - five years ago.  4.0 was earlier than that.  Anyone who is still using a JDK that old is making a mistake.